# Can't send object in Telegram Bot

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send anything except plain text from bot to user. I want to create echo for sending stickers for example. I'm using node-telegram-bot-api by yagop. 
Code:

```
bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
    polling: true
});
bot.on('sticker', function(msg){
    bot.sendSticker(msg.chat.id, msg.sticker);
});
```

And I have `Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: there is no sticker in the request`. This causes every time if I'm sending not a plain text.

How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `msg.sticker.file_id`instead of `msg.sticker`, for example:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]